# convert date/time from 24-hour format to 12-hour AM/PM using select query in php/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Displaying Time and date in 12hour format using mysql select query in php.

DB Name **Demo**

Table name **student**

**DB Structure**

```
Id      firstname    lastname      pubdate
int(11) varchar(100) varchar(100)  timestamp
```

I have inserted 5 records in student table and displayed using select query everything works great
but i am unable to display pubdate in proper 12 hour format!

please can somebody help me out in
acheiving it Thanks!

**Code**

```
$sql = "select id,firstname,lastname,pubdate from student";
$results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
   echo $row['id'];
   echo $row['firstname'];
   echo $row['lastname'];
   echo $row['pubdate'];

}
```

Answer (score 5):

use MySQL [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
DATE_FORMAT(pubdate,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
```

You query like that :-

```
$sql = "select id,firstname,lastname,
DATE_FORMAT(pubdate,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') as pubdate from student";
```

Comment: it's my pleasure :)- @Sjay

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept my answer @Sjay

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use :

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($row['pubdate']));
```

Live Sample

```
h is used for 12 digit time
i stands for minutes
s seconds
a will return am or pm (use in uppercase for AM PM)
m is used for months with digits
d is used for days in digit
Y uppercase is used for 4 digit year (use it lowercase for two digit)
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert date to 12 hour am/pm use

```
echo date('h:i:s a m/d/Y', strtotime($row['pubdate']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `date()` and `strtotime()` of PHP:

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s A", strtotime($row["pubdate"])); /* WILL ECHO 2015-11-10 02:50:24 PM */
```

Refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more date format.

Answer (score 1):

Use date() and strtotime() functions

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s A", strtotime($row["pubdate"]));
```